# Ejecutar un comando dentro de otro

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

He creado un comando `adivinar_numero` cuyo contenido se puede ver a continuación (funciona correctamente):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def adivinar_numero(ctx):
    jueg1 = discord.Embed(
        title = "__Adivina el número__",
        description = "Crearé un número random y tú tratarás de adivinarlo.\nEscribe **listo** para empezar."
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=jueg1)
```

Ahora quiero que el bot detecte la palabra "listo", pero únicamente si se ejecutó antes el comando `adivinar_numero`.

¿Es posible crear un nuevo comando "dentro de `adivinar_numero`" para conseguir esto?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español! Las imágenes con código no son bien vistas en este sitio. Necesitamos el código en formato texto para poder elaborar nuestras respuestas sin tener que reescribirlo desde cero.  [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/510683/edit) la pregunta y pega el código en lugar de la imagen. De paso mírate [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender nuestro funcionamiento y tambien ganar tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 1):

En vez de añadir un nuevo comando, puedes simplemente extender la funcionalidad de `adivinar_numero`.

Puedes hacer uso de la corutina [`Bot.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) para esperar hasta que el usuario escriba la palabra "listo" y continuar con la "segunda parte" del comando a continuación.

En la documentación (enlace en el párrafo de arriba) puedes leer más acerca de este método. Aplicado a tu problema el código quedaría así:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Recuerda activar el intent message_content
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.command(name="adivinar_numero")
async def adivinar_numero(ctx : commands.Context):
    jueg1 = discord.Embed(title="Adivina número", description="Escribe **listo**")
    await ctx.send(embed=jueg1)

    def check_start(new_message : discord.Message) -> bool:
        """
        Comprueba que en los mensajes posteriores:
        - El contenido del mensaje sea: "listo"
        - El mensaje se mande por el mismo canal en el que se ejecutó el comando
        - El mensaje sea de la misma persona que ejecutó el comando
        """
        return new_message.content.lower() == 'listo' and new_message.channel == ctx.channel and new_message.author == ctx.author

    await bot.wait_for('message', check=check_start)
    
    # No se ejecutará hasta que se cumplan las condiciones del wait_for
    await ctx.send('¡"listo" recibido!') 

    # "Segunda parte" del comando
    # ...
```